# Counting permuations in Python

Tags: python

What is the fastest way of counting the number of permutations? I have the following problem:

First I have this:

```
ncombos = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], years*n)
('a1', 'a1', 'a1')
('a1', 'a1', 'a2')
('a1', 'a1', 'a3')
('a1', 'a2', 'a2')
.... etc.....    
('a3', 'a3', 'a3')
```

The aim is to go through each one and calculate the number of permutations that each one has and construct an array with these values. I implemented this using:

```
nodes = np.ones(len(leafs)); i=0  #This will store the number of permutations

for j in ncombos:
    nodes[i] =len(list(set(itertools.permutations(np.asanyarray(j), n))))
    i = i+1
```

np.asanyarray(j) converts the ('a1','a1','a1') into formal ['a1','a1', 'a1'] which is need for permutations() to work. set erases the permutations which are identical. list makes a list of this. len calculates how many permutations can i make with a1, a1, a1.

So basically all I want is to count the number of permutations... However my code is extremely!!! slow ! Thank you!

Comment: Can you somewhat formally define your problem? I don't understand what exactly you want to calculate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use math. The number of permutations of a list is the factorial of the length of the list, divided by the product of the factorials of the multiplicity of each element (since sets of repeated elements are permuted with no effect).

```
import operator
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from math import factorial
def npermutations(l):
    num = factorial(len(l))
    mults = Counter(l).values()
    den = reduce(operator.mul, (factorial(v) for v in mults), 1)
    return num / den
```

Examples:

```
>>> npermutations([1,1,1])
1
>>> npermutations([1,2,3])
6
>>> npermutations([1,3,1,2,1,3,1,2])
420
```

Comment: I think this is similar, but not the same as what he wants to calculate (assuming I'm correct in thinking he wants permutations with replacement, aka cartesian product)

Comment: He quite clearly wants the number of permutations without replacement, but he's calculating that for every combination with replacement. (Though, I am reasonably sure there's an alternate approach to his problem that doesn't invoke combinatorial explosion...)

Comment: This is what I want ! It works perfect. Although I am not sure why, your function is a hell of a lot faster than my way of doing it. Any clue? Also, how would you make your method faster? is there any way ? Thanks!

Comment: My method doesn't enumerate every single permutation. It just uses math to calculate the number of permutations directly.

Comment: Ohh Im such a beginner to programming. I see, enumerating consumes a lot of memory. Thanks. Just asking to learn...Do you think your method can be improved or faster ???

Comment: It's pretty close to optimal, in that it's almost O(n) for every input (i.e. it takes time proportional to the length of the input list). Your overall operation, which is to loop over every single combination, is still going to be slow; to make that faster, you may have to reconsider your approach to the problem (I don't know what problem you are trying to solve).

Comment: @nneonneo This answer's formula should be called **ncombinations**, (though he may want nproducts for [products](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) which allows different orders) because you used the combination formula not the permutation formula which is `math.factorial(len(l))`. Not knowing that caused me problems with my anagram program for a whole day until seeking further information such as [permutations-without-repetitions-exclude-repeated-permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356027/permutations-without-repetitions-exclude-repeated-permutations).

Comment: @poikilos no, this answer is in fact the number of permutations of a list *ignoring duplicate permutations*, not the number of combinations. It divides not by “(n-r)!”, but by the number of ways to permute subsets of identical values.

Comment: @nneonneo ok, thanks. My problem turned out to be that I was using itertools.permutations which includes all orders (including duplicate results where same values are switched) for my actual loop, that's why my estimated total didn't match the actual result count--your total formula seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want permutations with replacement, this exists and is called the cartesian product. Itertools has a function for this, `product()`:

```
>>> for i in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3):
...     print i
...
('A', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'A')
('A', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'C', 'A')
('A', 'C', 'B')
('A', 'C', 'C')
('B', 'A', 'A')
('B', 'A', 'B')
('B', 'A', 'C')
('B', 'B', 'A')
('B', 'B', 'B')
('B', 'B', 'C')
('B', 'C', 'A')
('B', 'C', 'B')
('B', 'C', 'C')
('C', 'A', 'A')
('C', 'A', 'B')
('C', 'A', 'C')
('C', 'B', 'A')
('C', 'B', 'B')
('C', 'B', 'C')
('C', 'C', 'A')
('C', 'C', 'B')
('C', 'C', 'C')
```